# Relative imports in Tensorflow Object detection API

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to use the `tensorflow` object detection APIs for one of my personal projects. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) you can find the link to the repo for the same that needs to be cloned before using it. In this repo, there are multiple directories and are arranged in this fashion:

```
models
   + research
      + object_detection
      +
    + ....
    + ....
```

Now the `object_detection` is the one that is of use to me. So, I create a new directory in the parent directory `research` for my own models and try to use the functionalities given in the `object_detection` directory. Within the `object_detction` directory is a sub-directory `utils` which contains a bunch of `.py` files for certain utilities. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py) is a sample link for such a file in that directory. Now when I try to use this file in my code, it says `no module found: object_detection`. This is a relative import error but I am not getting how to resolve it. I just want to make sure that I can use each of the functionality without modifying the imports and this is doable because there is an `__init__` file in each sub-directory but somehow this isn't working. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [installation instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md), please add slim/ and models/ to your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, I assume that you already installed tensorflow/models.  Otherwise install it (and all its dependencies) either as explained [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) or in an [virtual environment](https://datasciencecampus.github.io/Installing-tensorflow-object-detection-API-notes/).

Either way you can import code from the object_detection API like so:

```
from object_detection import <myExample>
```

For your example that would be:

```
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
```